# rails acts_as_rateable undefined. what could be wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, undefined

I'm running rails 3 and have installed the acts_as_rateable gem by adding this "gem 'acts_as_rateable'" to my gemfile. Everything installed correctly after bundle install and I have put "acts_as_rateable" in my model. I have even restart the webserver multiple times and I still get this message:

undefined local variable or method `acts_as_rateable'

what am I missing????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so apparently 'acts_as_rateable' is really a plugin and not a gem. I had to move the folder into my vendor/plugins folder for it to work.